# Prove: Let $f : A \to B$ be a function such that $f^{-1}$ is also a function. Then $dom f = im f^{-1}$ and $im f = dom f^{-1}.$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Here's what I know:

Since $f^{-1}$ is a function, the function $f$ is one-to-one.

I know what I'm trying to prove, for example,

$f = \{(1,2), (2,3), (3,4)\}$ and then $f^{-1} = \{(2,1), (3,2), (4,3)\}$

So $dom f = \{1, 2, 3\}$ and $im f^{-1} = \{1, 2, 3\}$. The sets are equal.

...but I'm finding my issue is trying to put it into generic words.

I need to show that the sets are equal in both cases, so I will be using two set equality proofs and proving they are subsets of each other (they are equal, so of course they are).

All I have so far is the template.

Proof.
Suppose $f : A \to B$ is a function such that $f^{-1}$ is also a function.
Since $f^{-1}$ is a function, $f$ is one-to-one.
*Set equality template for first part of 'and' here.

Set equality template for second part of 'and' here.*
So $dom f = im f^{-1}$ and $im f = dom f^-1$.

As you can see, I know what I'm proving, but don't know how to say it generically.

Comment: You are being asked to prove the surjectivity of $f$ and $f^{-1}$. $f$ surjective means that, given any $b\in B$, there exists $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=b$. Do you see what it is you have to show now?

Answer (score 1):

$f^{-1}$ exists, which means for every $b\in B$, $f^{-1}(b)=a$ uniquely for specific $a$, which means $f$ is injective. Also You have:

By definition,
$$f^{-1}(Im(f))=dom(f)$$
(Since $Im(f)\subset B$)
So,
$$f(f^{-1}Im(f))=Im(f)=f(dom(f))=B$$
(This proves the existence of right inverse implies the function is surjective)

Then,
$$f^{-1}(B)=Im(f^{-1})$$

$$f^{-1}(B)=f^{-1}(Im(f))=dom(f)=Im(f^{-1})$$

---

$$f(A)=Im(f)$$

$$f^{-1}(f(A))=f^{-1}(Im(f))$$

$$A=dom(f)=f^{-1}(Im(f))$$
(This proves left inverse implies the inverse function is surjective)
$$Im(f^{-1})=f^{-1}(Im(f))$$

$$f(Im(f^{-1}))=Im(f)$$

Since $f(Im(f^{-1}))=dom(f^{-1})=B$, because $Im(f^{-1})=f^{-1}(B)\subset A$

$$dom(f^{-1})=Im(f)$$

I think it can be done in simple ways, but I am too tired to check.